# Should users encountering benign but irrelevant comments flag them as not needed?

Tags: support, comments, etiquette, comment-flags, no-longer-needed

I just flagged the following two comments from the question [Is it worth bothering to align AVX-256 memory stores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586384/is-it-worth-bothering-to-align-avx-256-memory-stores);

> Good question! I don't know the answer off the top of my head and
> don't have the time to research and write up a good answer, but I'm
> sure someone else will. In the meantime, I'll wonder aloud why you
> are writing your own code for this memory copying, rather than using
> something like Agner Fog's library that is already tuned for the
> instruction set of your choice.

and

> I see. Yes, being GPL would be a problem. But there isn't all that
> much difference between x86-32 and x86-64, so it seems like the vast
> majority of that optimized 32-bit code could be trivially ported to
> the 64-bit builds, gaining the performance improvement for
> free. Sure, you'd still have to write new code to target brand-new
> instruction sets like AVX-256, but their penetration in the wild is
> still very low, so it's probably not even worth it to think about
> shipping these builds. You'd only need this if you were running it
> on a backend server that you controlled.

These comments may have been helpful to the original asker, but do not
address the question at hand. So my questions are:

1. Should comments like these be flagged as "It's no longer needed."?
2. Regardless of what the policies are, will moderators bother with
   removing comments from five-year-old questions?
3. Does it matter if the comments to be flagged have received upvotes?
4. Does it matter if the author of the comments is a moderator and/or
   have a very high reputation?

As these are yes/no questions, yes/no answers supported by references
are perfectly fine.

Comment: Note: I don't consider it that comments can be upvoted, since they definitely can't be downvoted.  The only real purpose of tagging a comment is to help ensure that more important comments stay visible when the site decides to start collapsing them. Up to you if that influences your decision making about what to flag and what not to flag. You can hold the opinion that all comments are second class citizens and you can hold the opinion never to throw away value, there is no true right or wrong there.

Answer (score 7):

> Should comments like these be flagged as "It's no longer needed."?

Some of the comments here seem pretty heavy on technical jargon/domain knowledge, so I can't speak to that, but in general, yes, if a comment is not addressing the question, is no longer useful/relevant, it should be flagged as No Longer Needed.

The first comment you quoted should be flagged as NLN... but to be safe you could edit the question to include OP's stated restriction in a comment reply of "I can't use GPL libraries" (be sure to include a link to the comment in the edit description or in the body, even if it is deleted, so mods can see (if needed) that you weren't just making up requirements on OP's behalf).

Perhaps a better solution here would be to flag the top comment and recommend the entire thread of comments be migrated to chat; there's a lot of back-and-forth there that looks like it *could* be interesting to read, but doesn't necessarily need to remain on the question itself.

> Regardless of what the policies are, will moderators bother with removing comments from five-year-old questions?

Yes, age of comments is irrelevant to whether they deserve to be flagged. Besides, as comments get older, they *usually* become inherently less useful to keep around.

> Does it matter if the comments to be flagged have received upvotes?

Not much. A comment upvote just means someone found the comment useful/interesting.

> Does it matter if the author of the comments is a moderator and/or have a very high reputation?

No, moderation/curation actions like comment cleanup are always be made based on the content, not on authorship.

Comment: Note on "Does it matter if the comments to be flagged have received upvotes?" - more importantly upvote on comment may mean "I wanted to write exactly same one". In an extreme case something like "Please add the exception message" can collect 100+ upvotes (as every reader of the question sees this as necessary to be answer) till that message edited into the post and then th comment becomes absolutely NLN.

Comment: I'm willing to accept this answer, but you aren't citing anything so how can I know if this is recommended practice or just your opinion?

Comment: i mean... if a comment is no longer needed i don't see why there'd need to be a link to some docs stating that no longer needed means no longer needed

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I would consider "I wanted to write this comment" upvotes to indicate "this is useful/interesting"... presumably no one who is acting in good faith would write a comment they don't think is useful or interesting.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist There isn't much in the way of citations to give beyond "https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment". My answer above is my opinion, not "The Law(TM)", but it is provided as someone who has been on the site and active in site curation/moderation for many years, including successfully flagging many, many thousands of comments as NLN (almost 20,000). I did ping Cody in chat--he is a moderator and the author of the comments you're asking about, so maybe he will drop by to provide a response that is somewhat more... authoritative, with regard to what you're asking for.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist There is also the network-wide post on flagging comments here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments/237980#237980 In general, many of your specific questions are about "_should I take X into consideration when flagging_"; typically, I would say that, if X is not enumerated as something to take into consideration in the flag's description or in the help center pages on commenting/comment flagging, then X is not something you should take into consideration.

Comment: In other words, there's no flagging exception for "but this guy has a lot of reputation" or for "but this has upvotes", etc. The system _does_ have considerations built into it that are not accessible or not published _by design_ to prevent gaming said system via automated/un-mod-reviewed actions, but comment flags like this are almost always reviewed by moderators, who will determine whether a flag is correct or not. Handily, when you get a flag declined, the moderator can say why, and you can read about it in your personal flags page.

Comment: "Perhaps a better solution here would be to flag the top comment and recommend the entire thread of comments be migrated to chat" – I think usually, if you want action to be taken on the whole comment thread, it may be better to flag the post itself rather than an individual comment.

Comment: @V2Blast Possibly, I don't think I've ever seen a mod suggest a preference for users flagging the post vs flagging one of the comments for that. I usually recommend flagging a comment because if you flag the post, the system message about how to suggest migration of the _question_ to another site pops up if you include the word "move" or "migration"/"migrate", etc. in your flag text even though you aren't talking about migrating the question.

Comment: @TylerH: Ah, fair enough. I usually suggest flagging the post for issues beyond a single comment needing removal, because mods can't provide a custom response when declining comment flags, deleting the comment automatically dismisses the comment flag (there's no way to delete the comment without dismissing the flag), and there's no way to mark a comment flag as helpful *without* deleting the flag (IIRC).

Comment: @V2Blast Does manual mod migration to chat count as deleting the comment to the system there?

Comment: @TylerH: Yes, if a comment is deleted for any reason (whether or not it has been "moved" to chat through either user or moderator action), I believe flags on that comment are automatically dismissed as helpful.